# No drive letter, cant initialize, I/O errors...is my SSD dead?

Tags: ssd, chkdsk, diskpart

I have an SSD that is not recognized when I plug in via SATA. Tried all ports and swapped cables.

It is now attached to an SSD to USB dongle

- Not recognized or mounted in windows 7 (dont ask :)
- ran disk management to initialize but it gave me an I/O error
- ran DISKPART, disk is listed but no volumes
- tried to create partition and got an I/O error
- ran VOLMOUNT to try and run CHKDSK but was not listed
- running TEST DISK app on it now

2 questions:

1. Does this seem to be a dead drive? Likelihood?
2. If so, is the data recoverable? This was from a PC I tinkered with so no personal files but had some config files and such that would save me plenty of time

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try mounting it off a linux host and see if you can mount it, and see data

This should get you started.

https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/get-your-data-back-linux-based-data-recovery-tools/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will try. But just out of curiosity, what is about the linux system that would make it more capable of seeing the data?

Comment: More tools, better support for a variety of filesystems, not just windows. Also, way better recovery tools.